# Google Spreadsheet not automatically updating on published page

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/armstrongtransport.com/spreadsheets/d/1HlLKcST2uDNvB8Q1pJjDLdKKSEL8O5UhMbUZyC9EeMg/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true) that I share at work that does not update on the published webpage link that I send out. If new info in input, the webpage never updates even though it says it is set to "every 5 minutes". Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are seeing the cached page instead of the last version. Check your for browser help to see how to bypass your browser cache.

Comment: This still doesn't update even if using a new Incognito/Private window :(